# How can I send request to API Gateway via websocket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created a API gateway with websocket. And I added request/response integration to my lambda in $connect route. Then I deploy the API to staging and I can see there is a `wss` and `https` URL generated on staging page. 
Then I am using `wscat` command to test the websocket connection:

```
wscat -c wss://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev
```

But I get an error response: `error: Unexpected server response: 500`.

I don't have any authentication on the API. And I have checked my lambda log, it is not called. That means the request failed on API gateway. What could be the error in my API Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

The lambda you're integrating the $connect route to needs permission to be invoked by apigateway.

Add the following permission:

Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com

Effect: Allow

Action: lambda:InvokeFunction

Also enable Cloudwatch logs for API Gateway to get a better idea what's going on if it's failing before hitting your lambda.

Stages -> Logs/Tracing -> CloudWatch Settings -> Enable CloudWatch Logs